# MyBatis: How to return a map of lists?

Tags: java, mybatis

I have Googled this until I was blue in the face and could not find an answer. How can I configure MyBatis to return a Map of Lists ?

ie

```
HashMap<String, List<Foo>>
```

For example, if I had a query that returned all the orders for all my customers and I wanted to get it to return a Map containing a list of the orders keyed by the customer id.

EDIT

I found a way to do it by writing a custom ResultHandler, but would rather have MyBatis do it for me much like Hibernate does with either mapping or annotations.

Thanks.

Comment: Are you sure you don't want a List of Map(s)?

Comment: Quite sure, I simply want a map with one column ie customerID as they key and a list of another object ie order objects as the value.

Comment: I'm just wondering how will you create your hashmap in sql. Must be easy but for me it looks quite difficult. Well, first I think you have a myBatis map object that should be created by the framework. And then I'd rather try a list of "mapped" objects, e.g. beans that could be easily created. My opinion - I prefere list of beans.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest thing I have found was creating a new POJO and putting the `id` and list of objects in there.

**StringFoo.java**

```
public class StringFoo {
    String name;
    List<Foo> foos;
}
```

**Mapper.java**

```
List<StringFoo> findFoo(@Param("id") Long id);
```

**Mapper.xml**

```
<resultMap id="FooResultMap" type="com.package.StringFoo">
    <result property="name" column="name"/>
    <collection property="foo" resultMap="FooMapORJavaType"/>
</resultMap>
<select id="findFoo" resultMap="FooResultMap"></select>
```